# Suppose $G$ is cyclic group and $\sigma, \tau \in G$ are such that order$(\sigma)=12$ and order$(\tau)=21$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose $G$ is cyclic group and $\sigma, \tau \in G$ are such that order$(\sigma)=12$ and order$(\tau)=21$. Then the order of the smallest group constaing $\sigma$ and $\tau$ is ____.

I think the solution is LCM$(21,12)=84$ because a cyclic group obeys the converse of langrange's theorem.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Your intuition is correct. Let $H = \langle \sigma, \tau \rangle \subseteq G$. $H$ is therefore a cyclic group containing an element of order $12$ and of order $21$. In general, a cyclic group contains an element of a given order if and only if that order divides the order of the group - this is the converse to Lagrange's theorem I'm guessing you're talking about. Hence, the smallest possible order of $H$ is $lcm(12, 21) = 84$. As $\sigma, \tau \in G$, $12 \mid |G|$ and $21 \mid |G|$ so $84 \mid |G|$ and so this minimal possible order is attainable.

Comment: Sorry, typo. I'll edit the post.